# Calibrating undistortion reducing the size of image

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I trying calibrate my camera, i have generated calibration matrix and undistortion parameters of

```
array([[449.23763332,   0.        , 288.9949981 ],
       [  0.        , 509.88847329, 195.85872177],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,   1.        ]])

array([-0.38496184,  0.21366652, -0.00107046,  0.00090068, -0.07853835])
```

[image]

Following code for undistortion

```
file = 'snapshot_640_480_1.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(file)
h,  w = img.shape[:2]
newcameramtx, roi = cv.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx, dist, (w,h), 1, (w,h))

mapx, mapy = cv.initUndistortRectifyMap(mtx, dist, None, newcameramtx, (w,h), 5)
dst = cv.remap(img, mapx, mapy, cv.INTER_LINEAR)

# crop the image
x, y, w, h = roi
dst1 = dst[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cv.imwrite('calibresult.png', dst1)
display.Image(filename='calibresult.png')
```

Resulting image is getting reduced size of (95, 115, 3)

Is there any way i can undistort the image with same size ( resizing distort the image) ?

[image: undistorted image]

Comment: in initUndist... you are setting the output size (anything you like), but afterwards you are cropping the image. Your problem is: dst1 = dst[y:y+h, x:x+w] just remove that line

Comment: actually undistorted image is only inside the specific bounds @Micka , outer bounds holds just null info

Comment: ok sorry. Your output image should be of size w and h. Can you check all the values? x,y,w,h and the original image's size?

Comment: Yes @Micka, Thanks for response, those as follows (61, 301, 115, 95),  seems cv.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix( is undistorting w.r.t error of calibration :-|

Comment: you can adjust the cameraMatrix to your needs

Comment: thanks @Micka, its working as expected, would have understood the options :-|. would you add it to ans, i shall close the question

Comment: please answer the solution as an answer yourself. I will like to upload it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[cv.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#getoptimalnewcameramatrix) allows to alter the generated undistort image size by mentioning the input image size (w,h) and expected image size(w1,h1), by changing the expected image size

by changing the expected image size, we shall achieve referenced answer. Thanks for the inputs @Micka

```
file = r'snapshot_640_480_1.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(file)
h,  w = img.shape[:2]
# New Image shape to generate
w1,h1 = 5*w,5*h
newcameramtx, roi = cv.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx, dist, (w,h), 1, (w1,h1))

mapx, mapy = cv.initUndistortRectifyMap(mtx, dist, None, newcameramtx, (w1,h1), 5)
dst = cv.remap(img, mapx, mapy, cv.INTER_LINEAR)
```

Comment: this can cover right and bottom but cannot cover left and upper